# Divide query result by result of another query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL-Sever query that returns the Capacity available to a person on any particular day.
The result is returned against each assignment the person has planned on that particular day.

My problem is that it returns the total capacity for that day on each line of the query's result.
So when you show all the results for one day for one person, in a linked pivot table in excel (for example), you get the number of records multiplied by the base capacity.

I have written another query that counts the number of assignments per day per person.

I would like to divide the Capacity from the first query, by the number of records returned by the second query, but don't know how to join the queries together.

This is the query that returns the list of assignments by day with capacity:

```
SELECT 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay, 
  MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID, 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentActualWork, 
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.Capacity
FROM 
  MSP_EpmAssignment MSP_EpmAssignment,      
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay,
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView
WHERE   
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID 
  AND MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.TimeByDay = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay
```

This is the query that returns the number of assignments per day per person:

```
SELECT 
  count(TimeByDay) as DayCount 
FROM 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView 
  LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView
  ON MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView.AssignmentUID =
     MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.AssignmentUID
GROUP BY ResourceUID, TimeByDay
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code: highlight it, then press ^k. TIA.

Comment: Which SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: Answers can vary depending on the database, we need to know which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the only fields you need are those included in the query, try:

```
SELECT 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay, 
  MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID, 
  SUM(MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentActualWork) TotalWork, 
  MAX(MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.Capacity) Capacity
FROM 
  MSP_EpmAssignment,      
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay,
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView
WHERE   
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID 
  AND MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.TimeByDay = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay
GROUP BY
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay, 
  MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID
```

Alternatively, try changing the summary operation on Capacity in the pivot table to be MAX instead of SUM.

EDIT: To include a count of records for the same ResourceUID and TimeByDay in the details, try:

```
SELECT 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay, 
  MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID, 
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentActualWork, 
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.Capacity,
  count(*) over (partition by MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay,
                              MSP_EpmAssignment.ResourceUID) DayCount
FROM 
  MSP_EpmAssignment MSP_EpmAssignment,      
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay,
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView
  MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView
WHERE   
  MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID = MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID 
  AND MSP_EpmResourceByDay_UserView.TimeByDay = MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay
```

Comment: The query is actualy much more extensive than the code snippet I posted, but if solved at this level would be easily applied to the whole query.

I used the pivot table as an illustrative example but the data itself needs to be structured this way for other purposes and as such applying a MAX function will not work.
The capacity must be displayed against each individual assignment line as (Capacity/number of assignments per day for that user)
I cannot apply a SUM to the MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentActualWork field as in the main query I need these lines individually.

Comment: @VxD021: Then you need to tell us which database you are using.

Comment: This is an SQL-Server 2008 based database. Its the Microsoft Project Server 2010 Reporting Database

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was not even aware of the partition function. Thanks for your help Mark. It's much appreciated.